# How to find all publicly visible targets in a Bazel workspace

Tags: bazel

I am trying to query the list of Bazel targets having *public visibility*. Some of our Bazel targets have `visibility` specified explicitly, e.g.:

```
cc_library(
    name = "xxx_util",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public",],
    ...
)
```

while most targets are *implicitly public*, as their `BUILD` files have default public visibility specified, e.g.

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
```

I need a list of all such targets, so that I can copy their output to a certain location automatically after my Bazel workspace is built.

I am new to Bazel and can't figure out the query...

Answer (score 19):

I think the previous answer does cover the attribute query for visibility attribute restricted results. For posterity, I would add that if you simply want to find all targets from current directory, you could do:

```
bazel query ...
```

Comment: I think you meant:
`bazel query //...`

at least this is what worked for me.

Comment: No, I meant just `...`; this worked (executed from the root of the project, not sure if that matters).

Comment: `...` means "everything under the current directory", so if your current directory is the root of the project then `...` and `//...` are equivalent. But if you `cd` into a subdirectory, `...` will start showing only those targets under the subdirectory, while `//...` will continue showing everything.

Answer (score 11):

Look at this example: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query-how-to.html#which-of-those-are-small-medium-large

You need something like:

```
bazel query 'attr(visibility, "//visibility:public", //path/to/package:*)'
```

---

Update(2017-01-04): [@Curious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1585970/curious) was asking about querying for the effective visibility of a target, i.e. taking `default_visibility` into account. AFAIK Bazel doesn't support that; see [issue #4388](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4388).

Comment: or simply: bazel query 'attr(visibility, "//visibility:public", ...)'

Comment: **This works, but only partially**, only for those targets which have the visibility attribute specified explicitly, e.g. `visibility = ["//visibility:public"],` . My problem is that many of of our `BUILD` files have package level visibility specified in them e.g. `package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])` & I expect all targets in such `BUILD` files appear in my query... Looks like the package level visibility is not being propagated to the target, for querying purpose...

Comment: Ah, you need the effective visibility! I don't think bazel query can tell you that. I filed a feature request: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4388 . Unfortunately we don't have anyone dedicated to working on bazel query right now, so this will probably have to wait.

Comment: For files that have default_visibility, use this to find the targets that don't change visibility:
`bazel query 'attr(visibility, "", //path/to/package:*)'`

With a bit of work, you should be able to combine the results and get what you need. I don't think we have a better solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76602018/14430730) which helped me out.

You can use `bazel query 'visible(//foo, ...)'` to find all targets visible from `//some_target`.

So if `//foo` is a target in the root of workspace (`//:foo`), you will get all public visible targets **AND** some targets in same package with `//:foo`. What you need is just checking the BUILD file in workspace root.