# How do I query for targets visible from a specific targets?

Tags: bazel, bazel-query

Bazel uses the concept of `visibility` to limit which targets can depend on which targets. Given a target `//my:foo`, I am looking for a way to query Bazel for a list of targets visible to `//my:foo`.

Basically, I am trying to figure out which targets in the workspace the target `//my:foo` can depend on. Any idea if this is possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query has a [`visible` function](https://bazel.build/query/language#visible). So, `bazel query 'visible(//my:foo, //...)'` prints all the targets that `//my:foo` may depend on.